# Parsing verb-based argv in C++

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a C++ project that needs to take in the normal options `getopt` retrieves, but also is verb-based (`systemctl` is a good example, using sub-commands). How would I do this? (note: This is a minimal application, it would be best if it could be native LLVM C/C++ instead of using a library)

Comment: Check [`boost::program_options`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/program_options.html)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That isn't an option, as it is a minimal application, and I want to avoid outside libraries as much as possible.

Comment: _"...  as it is a minimal application ..."_ You'll see that may quickly turn out not to be one, if you're going to implement all of that your own.

Comment: Can you further elaborate on what you mean by verb based? Even if you can't express it in proper code, proper code interlaced with some pseudo code or comments is better than just a brief description.

Comment: @Paul I believe they mean kinda _commands_ like `start`, `stop`, etc.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually parse the options using `std::strcmp()`:

```
int main(int, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        enum class verb_type {none, start, stop, restart, status};

        verb_type verb = verb_type::none;
        std::string service;

        for(auto arg = argv + 1; *arg; ++arg)
        {
            if(verb == verb_type::none)
            {
                if(!std::strcmp(*arg, "--help"))
                {
                    print_help();
                    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
                }
                else if(!std::strcmp(*arg, "start"))
                    verb = verb_type::start;
                else if(!std::strcmp(*arg, "stop"))
                    verb = verb_type::stop;
                else if(!std::strcmp(*arg, "restart"))
                    verb = verb_type::restart;
                else
                    throw std::runtime_error("unknown operation: " << std::string(*arg));
            }
            else // get noun
            {
                service = *arg;
                if(!is_service(service))
                    throw std::runtime_error("Unrecognized service: " + service);
            }
        }

        // use verb & service here....
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unknown exception." << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can also do normal `getopt` options processing before hand if you like and use `optind` to tell you were the non-getopt arguments begin:

```
        // start where getopt ends
        for(auto arg = argv + optind; *arg; ++arg)
        {
            // ... etc ...
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to figure out where the options end. That pretty much solves my problem.